# TODO-list: How to add items on the list immediately, before server responded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, web, architecture

I'm creating a TODO-list using React.

When the user fills all the fields and presses the ADD button, I want immediately add the item to the list, and then send this item to the server. Then, the server responses with the ID of this item in the database.

The problem is that my app uses item IDs to remember which items are selected at the moment. Also, I want to use IDs in the browser's address bar. But the item ID is being generated on the server, so I cannot figure it out before server responded.

What options do I have?

Comment: ideally, you should be pushing the item to list once the record is created from the server. Is there some specific reason to handle it this way?

Comment: @AneesMuhammed not OP, but one reason for implementing such behaviour could be to have an [Optimistic UI](https://medium.com/distant-horizons/using-optimistic-ui-to-delight-your-users-ac819a81d59a)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add items to a react list without relying on the server-side ID.

If you *really* need the ID generated by the back-end, I don't think this is possible.

You could of course use some temporary front-end ID (e.g. based on an educated guess) and replace that with the actual ID once the back-end responded, but that would obviously require some obscure bookkeeping and mapping.

It also depends on the way your ID's work. If an item-ID is a combination of the user and the item, the above should be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure we are on the same page but u can use local storage to save data and do your local stuff before server response